# Android ViewPager, how to make sibling views smaller and darker

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm wondering how to implement a horizontal list of users, that become bigger and brighter once they are chosen:

[image: view]

I'm thinking about ViewPager with overriden getPageWidth so that it shows 3 items at the same time, but I don't know how do make the sibling views look differently then the one in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

That would have been pretty easy to achieve with the Gallery widget that is now unfortunately deprecated.
But there is the EcoGallery project https://github.com/falnatsheh/EcoGallery that has the same functionalities and works pretty well.
To transform the view in the center you can simply subclass the EcoGallery and override the

```
getChildStaticTransformation
```

method.
BTW you can override exactly the same method also on the ViewPager.
It's pretty easy to find loads of good examples of how to use this method.